# Zookeeper status checking with Ansible failing

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I am trying to find the status of Zookeeper process by shooting **/path/to/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status** and checking the **rc** variable. But the ansible says that output doesn't have the rc variable in output.

I am attaching few snippets:

Here, the output shows rc

```
changed: [staging] => {
    "changed": true, 
    "cmd": [
        "/path/to/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh", 
        "status"
    ], 
    "delta": "0:00:00.222272", 
    "end": "2017-10-17 14:30:23.937679", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "/path/to/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh", 
            "_uses_shell": false, 
            "chdir": null, 
            "creates": null, 
            "executable": null, 
            "removes": null, 
            "warn": true
        }
    }, 
    "rc": 0, 
    "start": "2017-10-17 14:30:23.715407", 
    "stderr": "JMX enabled by default\nUsing config: /path/to/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg", 
    "stderr_lines": [
        "JMX enabled by default", 
        "Using config: /path/to/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg"
    ], 
    "stdout": "Mode: follower", 
    "stdout_lines": [
        "Mode: follower"
    ]
}
```

And ansible shows the following errors

```
fatal: [staging]: FAILED! => {
"failed": true, 
"msg": "The conditional check 'output.rc != 0' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (output.rc != 0): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'}
```

Task to get the output variable:

```
- name : "Check Zookeeper Service"
  command : /path/to/zookeeper/bin/zkServer.sh status
  register : output
```

Task which compares the rc variable

```
- name: "Checking RC"
  fail: msg="Zookeeper Service is DOWN"
  when: output.rc != 0
```

Could you please tell me what can be the problem here?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code of your task

Comment: I have added necessary tasks, could you please check it again @KonstantinSuvorov? Thanks.

Comment: Does the "check rc" task go just after "check zookeeper"?

Comment: No, there are couple of tasks in between as well which gets skipped but they do register the same variable.

Comment: That is the problem. `register:` do register result even for skipped tasks.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to avoid that ? Because I want to use the same variable.

Comment: This is not possible. See my answer and a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comments:

> – Does the "check rc" task go just after "check zookeeper"?
>
> – No, there are couple of tasks in between as well which gets skipped but they do register the same variable.
>
> – That is the problem. `register:` do register result even for skipped tasks.

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41335880/2795592) for details.